# android:onClickListener not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I'm reading the next book "Exploring Android" Version 0.7 https://commonsware.com/AndExplore/

and its Android sample project uses Data Binding library

So there is one layout and it contains line `android:onClickListener="@{(v) -> holder.onRowClick.invoke(model)}">`:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:onClickListener="@{(v) -> holder.onRowClick.invoke(model)"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

But it won't compile.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     res\layout\todo_row.xml:13: AAPT: error: attribute android:onClickListener not found.
```

But some of such listeners works, e.g. `android:onCheckedChanged`, though Android Studio shows a warning:

[image]

I don't really like all this (lambdas, functions in xml) but it seems Android allows some of that and it can be used for writing MVVM based app

So why does `android:onCheckedChanged` work and for `android:onClickListener` I get "not found" error?

Comment: should be ```android:onClick```

Comment: @JakeB, no, it's a different thing. It's for click method which is overrided in Java/Kotlin class

Comment: do you have the clicklistener java code in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you miss `}` in the end.
should be

```
 android:onClickListener="@{(v) -> holder.onRowClick.invoke(model)}"
```

Comment: so it affects the whole property, wrong lamba/function and it can't find the method...

Answer (score 1):

You should try `android:onClick="@{(v) -> holder.onRowClick.invoke(model)"` instead of `android:onClickListener="@{(v) -> holder.onRowClick.invoke(model)"`

Comment: definitely not.